# NLTK Tokenizer encoding issue

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

After tokenizing, my sentence contains many weird characters. How can I remove them?
This is my code:

```
def summary(filename, method):
    list_names = glob.glob(filename)
    orginal_data = []
    topic_data = []
    print(list_names)
    for file_name in list_names:
        article = []
        article_temp = io.open(file_name,"r", encoding = "utf-8-sig").readlines()
        for line in article_temp:
            print(line)
            if (line.strip()):
                tokenizer =nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
                sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(line)
                print(sentences)
                article = article + sentences
        orginal_data.append(article)
        topic_data.append(preprocess_data(article))
    if (method == "orig"):
        summary = generate_summary_origin(topic_data, 100, orginal_data)
    elif (method == "best-avg"):
        summary = generate_summary_best_avg(topic_data, 100, orginal_data)
    else:
        summary = generate_summary_simplified(topic_data, 100, orginal_data)
    return summary
```

The `print(line)` prints a line of a txt. And `print(sentences)` prints the tokenized sentences in the line.

But sometimes the sentences contains weird characters after nltk's processing.

```
Assaly, who is a fan of both Pusha T and Drake, said he and his friends 
wondered if people in the crowd might boo Pusha T during the show, but 
said he never imagined actual violence would take place.

[u'Assaly, who is a fan of both Pusha T and Drake, said he and his 
friends wondered if people in\xa0the crowd might boo Pusha\xa0T during 
the show, but said he never imagined actual violence would take 
place.']
```

Like above example, where is the `\xa0` and `\xa0T` from?

Comment: \xa0 is an unicode character representing a [no-break space](http://www.codetable.net/hex/a0). Your original text probably contains part UTF-8 encoding, part unicode encoding. Try to re-encode your original text file to UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = u'Assaly, who is a fan of both Pusha T and Drake, said he and his friends wondered if people in\xa0the crowd might boo Pusha\xa0T during the show, but said he never imagined actual violence would take place.'

# method 1 
x.replace('\xa0', ' ')

# method 2
import unicodedata
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x)

print(x)
```

Output:

```
Assaly, who is a fan of both Pusha T and Drake, said he and his friends wondered if people in the crowd might boo Pusha T during the show, but said he never imagined actual violence would take place.
```

Reference: [unicodedata.normalize()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)